# Constant HDD access noise

Tags: hard-drive

I recently set up a Dell OptiPlex 3070 as a fileserver running Debian. The system disk is a SSD and the data disc is a Hitachi Deskstar 8GB NAS disc which was previously used in a Synology Diskstation. I just noticed, that the data disc is constantly spinning and making a short access noise all few seconds. I thought this was some process repeatedly accessing the disk, but the disc makes the sound even if it is not mounted and even if there is no system running (e.g. during editing the BIOS settings).
If I manually send the disk to sleep the noise stops. Could this be the sign of the disk going faulty? I haven't noticed problems accessing the disc though.
These are the current settings according to hdparm:

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       HGST HDN728080ALE604                    
        Serial Number:      VJGNX1VX            
        Firmware Revision:  A4GNW91X
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0; Revision: ATA8-AST T13 Project D1697 Revision 0b
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
        Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 9
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors: 15628053168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:     7630885 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     8001563 MBytes (8001 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
        Form Factor: 3.5 inch
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
        Advanced power management level: 254
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Advanced Power Management feature set
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    Media Card Pass-Through
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    URG for READ_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
           *    URG for WRITE_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    unknown 119[6]
                unknown 119[7]
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Host-initiated interface power management
           *    Phy event counters
           *    NCQ priority information
           *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
                Non-Zero buffer offsets in DMA Setup FIS
           *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
                Device-initiated interface power management
                In-order data delivery
           *    Software settings preservation
                unknown 78[7]
                unknown 78[10]
                unknown 78[11]
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
           *    SANITIZE feature set
           *    OVERWRITE_EXT command
           *    Extended number of user addressable sectors 
           *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
           *    READ BUFFER DMA command
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
                frozen
        not     expired: security count
        not     supported: enhanced erase
        936min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000cca261c980c1
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 000cca
        Unique ID       : 261c980c1
Checksum: correct
```

Edit - Smart readout:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     HGST Deskstar NAS
Device Model:     HGST HDN728080ALE604
Serial Number:    VJGNX1VX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 261c980c1
Firmware Version: A4GNW91X
User Capacity:    8.001.563.222.016 bytes [8,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jul 11 14:35:33 2022 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  101) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (1117) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   134   134   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       104
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   156   156   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       396 (Average 449)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       16089
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   128   128   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       18
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       25893
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       13373
 22 Helium_Level            0x0023   100   100   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   086   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       17436
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   086   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       17436
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   146   146   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 18/48)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     25403         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     25080         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     24505         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23762         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23090         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     22346         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     21602         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     20882         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     20137         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     19450         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     19022         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     18748         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     18415         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     18097         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17777         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17403         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17039         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16676         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16317         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15939         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15267         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

[Recording of the noise.](http://sndup.net/tdwv)

Comment: Have you got the full smart data readout? My rule of thumb is if the drive has been used for over 5 years / 43830 hours it's time for replacement. When I have had a drive do the same thing it's getting close to failure.

Comment: I just read some comment in a german board, that some NAS drives are known to make these recurring noises. I haven't found some official statement yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your noise is something you had not heard in the past I would replace the drive. If you can't tell when this noise started I see no danger.

**Analysis of your SMART report**

To reduce noise I would install rubber mounts.
I consider the maximum temperature of your drive as being too high - even for a 7200 rpm drive. What is your ambient temperature?
Installling a ventilator nearby might help.
I don't know your load profile, compared to mine your start/stop count of 16000 appears high to me over roughly 3 years of use. I would consider adjusting some settings.